# How to handle query being parsed in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express

I am using `fetch` to fetch data from a URL in javascript.

The query part of the URL is a `sqlite3` query that I am submitting. It usually works perfectly, but when there is an occurrence of a `%` character in the query it seems to encode the entire query

For example: replacing spaces with `%20`.

This is problematic because this encoded query is then run against the database to obtain the information rather than the submitted query. Is there a way to decode the query or perhaps stop it from being encoded in the first place?

Here is my fetch method:

```
fetch(`/api/isos/${this.iso}/` + endpoint)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
     })
     .then((json) => {
        if(json.error)
            this.error = json;
        else 
            this[dataName] = json; 
        this.running = false
     });
```

Comment: What does the URL look like? There is a built in `decodeURI()` method that may help. However, this just sounds dangerous, are you sure you want the client sending full queries to your API?

Comment: if you want to decode whole query string then use `decodeURI()` other wise use `decodeURIComponent()` method.

Comment: I have tried decodeURIComponent() and decodeURI(). The problem is that these functions do not work whenever a %s in a printf statement is present or a like statement is present because it picks up the %s or % followed by the like string as an incorrect encoding and fails.